# JPA Collection with user defined order

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

consider following model:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private List<String> phoneNumber = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

In front-end user should be able define order of phone numbers in this sample with drag and drop or something like that. Can you tell me what is the most effective way to handle this use case? I found solution with jpa annotation `@OrderColumn` which generates additional column. But I guess if I need re-order items, solution is delete all from collection and save it again with new order right? I afraid that is not very elegant solution. Can you give me your advice? Thank you.

Comment: It's OrderColumn, not ColumnOrder. And no, why would you have to delete all from collection and save again (not that it would cause any performance difference)? Why couldn't you simply reorder the elements of the List?

Comment: thanks, I fixed annotation name. Yes,  you are right. But I still don't know if this is the most effective way to handle it. Also there some disadvantages of @OrderColumn

Comment: Well, you have to understand how it works. In particular, if two rows end up having the same value in it, or if there is a missing value, then you will miss elements or have nulls in your lists.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I have null in list? I tried explicitly add null value into list and save entity with it, and null value isn't reflected into database.

Comment: By having, in your database rows with their order column set to 0, 1 and 3 for example. IIRC, when you load the entity, you will have a null at index 2. Maybe it doesn't work this way anymore.

Comment: When I tried OrderColumn I found if you change order of any record (or removing) all record orders for given entity are recalculated, so your ordering is always from 0 to X, where X is number of items - 1

Comment: Sure. The problems occur when you don't go through that collection to delete, insert or update an element (like a SQL query or something).